# Как добавить узел в xml?

Tags: c#, xml

Есть файл XML:

```
 <JOBS>
 <job ID="1" CheckForScan="True" JobName="new job (1)" Information="" PathToInputFolder="D:\test\input" PathToOutputFolder="D:\test\output" PathToErrorsFolder="D:\test\error" ParseSubfolders="False" UseFilter="True" Filter="*.txt" KindOfSort="Without sorting" Ascending="False" UseTemplateForTheFileName="True" TemplateForTheFileName="%ORIGNAME%.%ORIGEXT%7" UseArchiveFolder="True" PathToArchiveFolder="D:\test\archive" ScanInterval="True" TimeInterval="1" ScanDate="16.08.2017 10:16:16" Daily="False" KindOfScan="" NextScan="" PreviousScan="" /> 
 <job ID="2" CheckForScan="True" JobName="new job (2)" Information="" PathToInputFolder="D:\test\input" PathToOutputFolder="D:\test\output" PathToErrorsFolder="" ParseSubfolders="True" UseFilter="True" Filter="*.AVI" KindOfSort="Without sorting" Ascending="False" UseTemplateForTheFileName="False" TemplateForTheFileName="" UseArchiveFolder="True" PathToArchiveFolder="D:\test\archive" ScanInterval="False" TimeInterval="1" ScanDate="16.08.2017 14:07:03" Daily="True" KindOfScan="" NextScan="" PreviousScan="" /> 
 <settings MaxThreads="5" EndPosition="0" MaxAttempts="" WaitingTime="" /> 
 </JOBS>
```

При необходимости узлы job добавляются:

```
 xDoc.Element("JOBS").Add(new XElement("job", new XAttribute("ID", "newOne"),..... ))
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как добавить теги в цикле? Допустим есть двумерный массив с именем тега и значением.

Comment: Использовать операторы ```for``` или ```foreach```

Comment: А зачем вы удалили предыдущий вопрос? Он вполне себе имеет смысл.

Comment: `var jobs = xDoc.Element("JOBS"); foreach (...) jobs.Add(new XElement(...));`?

Comment: Восстановлю, но боюсь, что ответ не получу.

Comment: VladD, да что-то вроде того.

Comment: @АлександрПузанов: А вы восстановите, у меня есть ответ :)